# Event Handling in Chaco

Tags: python, chaco

When hovering over a data point in Chaco, I would like a small text box to appear, with the text I desire. Also, when I click on a data point (or close enough), I would like my program to take a certain action.

I have seen relevant parts of the Chaco documentation, but implementing them has proved to be difficult. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing first on the first (hover->textbox) issue, can you better explain what you've tried so far and how it's not working?  E.g.,

```
from enthought.enable.tools import hover_tool

tool = hover_tool.HoverTool(theplot, callback=showtext)
```

etc?  There's a more complex example of hover-tool use [here](https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/Chaco/trunk/examples/toolbar_plot.py?rev=22527) (shows a PlotToolbar rather than just a textbox) which you might be able to adapt.

Comment: I suppose my main woe has to do with packaging. I originally had the debian package to install, but I had no hover_tool module. So I compiled from source, and I still do not have the module listed. In fact, that file isn't in the examples that were installed my machine. Sorry for the late response, I've been at work all day. I will look into other modules and see if I can work out a solution on my own. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Debian may have an older version, but the sources to ETS (the Enthought Tool Suite, which includes Chaco and its underlying technologies/dependencies) seem up to date -- see http://code.enthought.com/source/ and use ETSProjectTools as per that page's recommendations, start with svn co https://svn.enthought.com/svn/enthought/ETSProjectTools/trunk then follow the docs at https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/wiki/SVNScripts .